# Java Table & inheritance multiple

Tags: android, inheritance

I want to do something but I'm not sure it is possible to do that.

I have :
a class A with one methode M
a class A' inherited of A with one method M'
a class A" inherited of A with one method M"

Then I've created a table
    private A"[] myTable = new A"[10];

And I add object A, A' and A"

```
  myTable[0] = new A
  myTable[1] = new A'
  myTable[2] = new A"
  myTable[3] = new A
```

==> It works.

Now, when I want to navigate in my table

```
for(int i = 0; i < myTable.length; i++)
{
     Here I can access methode of class A and A" but not A'
      myTable[i].M ==> OK
      myTable[i].M" ==> OK
      myTable[i].M' ==> KO
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Only method signatures on A are available to all.  A common interface is a good way to go.

Comment: it's possible, show us how you tried with code? there must be something wrong with code.